# Parsing a JSON file from a S3 Bucket

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am relatively new to Amazon Web Services.

I need help on parsing a JSON file from an S3 Bucket using Python. I was able to read in the JSON file from S3 using the S3 trigger connected to the lambda function and display it on Cloud-Watch aswell. I need help on how to parse the "results" from the JSON file and calculate max, min and average of the "Results".

Here is my JSON file:

```
Student = [{"Student_ID": 1,
    "Name":"Erik",
    "ExamSubject": "English",
    "Result": 72.3,
    "ExamDate": "9/12/2020",
    "Sex": "M"},



{"Student_ID": 2,
    "Name":"Daniel",
    "ExamSubject": "English",
    "Result": 71,
    "ExamDate": "9/12/2020",
    "Sex": "M"},


{"Student_ID": 3,
    "Name":"Michael",
    "ExamSubject": "English",
    "Result": 62,
    "ExamDate": "9/12/2020",
    "Sex": "M"},


{"Student_ID": 4,
    "Name":"Sven",
    "ExamSubject": "English",
    "Result": 73,
    "ExamDate": "9/12/2020",
    "Sex": "M"},


{"Student_ID": 5,
    "Name":"Jake",
    "ExamSubject": "English",
    "Result": 84.15,
    "ExamDate": "9/12/2020",
    "Sex": "M"},
]


print(Student)
```

and here is the code I have used on the lambda function so far:

```
import json
import boto3


s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

   bucket =  'finalyearpro-aws'
   key = 'StudentResults.json'


      try:
        data = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        json_data = data['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')



    print (json_data)


except Exception as e:

    raise e
```

How do I add to this code to make it read the "Results" from the JSON file, do analysis on it (max, min, average) and display on Lambda console.

Answer (score 7):

You can load the document using [`boto3.resource('s3').Object(...).get()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.get) and then parse it into python with [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  bucket =  'finalyearpro-aws'
  key = 'StudentResults.json'

  obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
  data = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
  json_data = json.loads(data)

  print(json_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

`json.loads(json_data)` will parse the json string and create list of dicts (for this data) from it. After that you can iterate over the list and do whatever you want, i.e.

```
data = json.loads(json_data)
min([r['Result'] for r in data])
```

Comment: I get this error when I put it into the lambda console:                                                                      Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': unindent does not match any outer indentation level (lambda_function.py, line 18)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 18\n           data = json.loads(json_data)\n"
  ]
}

Comment: @NimraSajid Indentation problem - you know, regular python stuff - check that spaces are correct on this line - should be indented as much as line above

Comment: Yh im new at python so im just figuring it out as I go along. Python is really tight on indentation.

Answer (score 1):

boto3 has switched to a new resource format (see https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/56). If you are getting error `'S3' object has no attribute 'Object'`, please try the following:

```py
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Bucket('bucket-name').Object('object-key')
jsonStr = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
```